# How do I install AcmeDemoBundle on Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

How do I install AcmeDemoBundle on Symfony 2.8?

I have Symfony 2.8 and I dont't have AcmeDemoBundle in this version of Symfony, but I want it. It is possible install this bundle? And how may I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a demo of Symfony, the best is to use `git clone https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo`

AcmeDemoBundle is deprecated since long time!